# Elasticsearch Error Response 5019: Illegal Argument

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

ElasticSearch is returning the following error upon reindexing a Magento 2.3 product catalog. I am unsure as to what the amasty_xsearch_fulltext.img is referring to.

> Elasticsearch engine returned an error response. item id: 5019. Error
> type: "illegal_argument_exception", reason "startOffset must be
> non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must
> not go backwards startOffset=430,endOffset=435,lastStartOffset=431 for
> field 'amasty_xsearch_fulltext.img'".

What are the offsets and where should I be looking to fix this issue?

Comment: did you recently add Synonyms to your Magento setup? This is some kind of bug with Amasty. Try deleting synonyms (System->Amasty Elastic Search ->Manage Synonyms). I have the same issue. I have taken it down to a single synonym item: "Hard drive, HDD, storage drive, storage, RAID, back up, back up drive". I still dont know what exactly is causing it though.

Comment: Yes, Elasticsearch does not work with multi word synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete synonyms from your Amasty ElasticSearch "Manage Synonyms" (System->Amasty ElasticSearch->Manage Synonyms)

For some reason it doesn't like when there are similar words or phrases connected to the original word.

Example:
HDD, back up, back up drive

This throws an error for me.

I'm not an ElasticSearch specialist so I cant exactly say why this happens.

UPDATE:

Got official word from Amasty:

"Multi-word synonyms may not work properly with Elasticsearch engine, please refer to Elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html

So looks like you can only use one word synonyms.

UDPATE: even after testing multiple times a working combination of words, on production site it failed.

I would not use that feature because its just unreliable and there is no validation on text input.